# given choices for argparse argument, can I use shortcuts for them?

Tags: python, argparse

```
import argparse
p = argparse.ArgumentParser()
p.add_argument('foo', choices=['run', 'halt'])
```

Is it somehow possible to pass 'r' instead of 'run' and 'h' instead of 'halt' in the command line? The only way I can think of, is adding those choices and assigning them the relevnat commands, i.e.:

```
p.add_argument('foo', choices=['run', 'r', 'h', 'halt'])
if args.foo in ('r', 'run'):
    # do something...
```

Comment: I believe the only way to do it is as you have done, as you can see from the documentation: https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#choices, the value passed will be checked for a exact match in the given choices

Comment: The choice mechanism uses a simple `in` test - `astr in action.choices`.  If `choices` is a list it has to be an exact match.  `choices` could also be a dictionary, which matches keys.  But it could also be some fancy class of your own design (it also has to iterable to show the help).  Another option is to use the `type` function to test the values.